# Is there a way to make this code more efficient and smaller?

Tags: python, performance, binary, decimal

I’ve just written this code for converting decimal to binary, using the dividing by 2 method. It works perfectly, but i was just wondering if there was a way to make it more efficient and easier to read.

```
def binary(d):
    stop = False
    c = []

    while stop == False:
        b = d%2
        if b == 0:
            d = d/2
        else:
            d = d/2
            b = 1
        c.append(b)

        if d == 1:
            c.append(1)
            stop = True

    c.reverse()
    c="".join(map(str,c))
    return(c)

d = int(input("enter number:"))
print(binary(d))
```

(I have only just started learning python)

Comment: If you have **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If not, give a [mcve]. Either way, code must be **in the question** on the SE network.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `bin()` or `format()`

```
num = 42

print bin(num)
# 0b101010
print "{0:#b}".format(num)
# 0b101010
print "{0:b}".format(num)
# 101010
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple method.

```
x=10
bin(x)
```

it will give you binary form of number 10. 
It will return '0b1010', very simple.
Try it , if you face any problem just reply back. Enjoy:)

As you wanted , I optimized the code , used some shortcut by keeping your logic intact in the code.

```
def binary(decimal):
    temp = []
    while True:
        binary_num = 0 if decimal % 2 == 0 else 1
        decimal = int(decimal / 2)
        temp.append(binary_num)
        if int(decimal) == 1:
            temp.append(1)
            break
    return "".join(map(str, temp.reverse()))


DECIMAL = int(input("enter number:"))
print(binary(DECIMAL))
```

Comment: thanks, that works perfectly! As i’m just elarnj python, i’m just wondering if there’s a way of compressing the code i wrote so i can see how, as i don’t really mind about what the code does, just how i write it